# Can I call directly operator() without creating a temporary object?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I've the following utility function to convert a given string to integer.

```
class convertToInt:public std::unary_function<const char*, int>
{

        public:
                int operator()(const char* cNumber)
                {
                        try
                        {
                                int result = boost::lexical_cast<int>(cNumber);
                                return result;
                        } catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& error)
                        {
                                std::cerr << "Error in converting to number "<< error.what() << std::endl;
                                return -1;
                        }
                }

};
```

When I want to actually use this utility function, I've to do the following.

```
  convertToInt cStrToInt;
  int iNumberToCheck = cStrToInt(argv[1]);
```

I'm just wondering, is there a way, I can directly call

```
int iNumberToCheck = convertToInt(argv[1]);
```

Comment: `int iNumberToCheck = convertToInt()(argv[1]);` ???

Comment: Please note that this still creates a temporary object because actually "convertToInt()" creates a convertToInt object. Thus creating a global function object will not be less efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is a member function and requires an object for it to be invoked on. You could use an unnamed temporary instead:

```
int iNumberToCheck = convertToInt()(argv[1]);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that the temporary object has 0 cost with mild optimizations enabled.  Since the temporary has not state, the compiler will optimize away the instance.

Comment: Thanks hmjd. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function static, so that it does not require an instance. The call has to be scoped.

You can also create the temporary as part of your larger expression (rather than using a named variable), which may seem less efficient but in practice is probably optimized to the same thing by your compiler.

Edit to add: `static` won't work for operator(), so you would need to rework to use that option.

Comment: Is it legal to create a `static` `operator(...)`?

Comment: @NikBougalis no it's not, and I missed that the function was actually operator() when I first wrote the answer. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the functor at the call-site, then you why not just turn it into a function?

```
int convertToInt(const char* cNumber)
{
    /*...*/
}

int iNumberToCheck = convertToInt(argv[1]);
```

Comment: If you've already got it as a function object (because you are passing it to something that expects a functor, or because it has to be virtual, or some other reason), why repeat the code in another function?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a statically-initialized global variable, which helps avoid [the static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). Static initialization requires the class to be an aggregate type. Just use the braces to initialize it:

```
struct convertToIntF
{
    int operator()(const char* cNumber) const
    {
        try
        {
            int result = boost::lexical_cast<int>(cNumber);
            return result;
        } 
        catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast& error)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in converting to number "<< error.what() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
};

convetToIntF converToInt = {};
```

Now, if the function object stores state or inherits from a class that is not an aggregate, this won't work. However, in C++11, its fairly trivial to write an adaptor that can static initialize any default constructible function object:

```
template<class F>
struct static_
{
    template<class... T>
    auto operator()(T && ... x) const -> decltype(F()(std::forward<T>(x)...))
    {
        static F f;
        return f(std::forward<T>(x)...);
    }
};
```

Then it can be initialized like this:

```
static_<convetToIntF> converToInt = {};
```

Comment: Careful. This is fine as written, but even a moderate change might invalidate the aggregate assumption and break the program (in the case of C++11, silently). Plus you rule out a lot of interesting behavior for function objects by requiring this.

Comment: @jerry In C++03, it will break with a compile error. In C++11, its fairly trivial to write an adaptor that can static initialize any default constructible function object(you can in C++03 as well, but its not very trivial).

Answer (score 0):

In this very simple case, an anonymous object will probably work fine, as others have pointed out. If you have a more complex class with state, however, consider the singleton pattern:

```
class SingletonFunctor
{
    private:

        // some private state

        // for a hybrid approach, the constructor could be public
        SingletonFunctor()
        {
            // initialize state
        }

     public:

        static const SingletonFunctor& GetSingleton()
        {
            static const SingletonFunctor _singleton;

            return _singleton;
        }

        SomeType operator() (SomeOtherType param) const
        {
            // do something interesting
        }            
};

int main (void)
{
    SomeType firstVal = SingletonFunctor::GetSingleton()(SomeOtherType());

    // ...
    // later

    // no need to instantiate another object
    SomeType secondVal = SingletonFunctor::GetSingleton()(SomeOtherType());
}
```

Be careful with this pattern if you mutate state, it can then have all the same problems as a global variable (especially with multithreading).